# Spring boot REST application not working without Build Path in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, spring-rest

I'm facing an issue where our spring boot application will only run if a subproject is included. A rough project sketch:

> - Backend
>
>   This is where the Main Class is located. This project also contains the spring repository which are exposed via REST, the filters and REST configuration. The data itself is included in the backend-module project.
> - backend-module
>
>   This is where the actual Java Classes which hold the data are located. They are used in conjunction with hibernate.

Now the application works fine unless I remove the backend-module from the Java Build Path in the eclipse Project preferences. But if I remove the reference the application launch will fail but not for a missing component from the backendmodule but for missing spring boot components:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/repository/support/RepositoryInvokerFactory
```

The pom.xml files of the project are almost the same.

I'll happily include all the information someone may need.
Thanks

## EDIT 1:

The pom.xml of the Backend Project.

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>backend</groupId>
    <artifactId>Backend</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <description>Rest Backend</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <!-- use UTF-8 for everything -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>cis</groupId>
            <artifactId>backend-module</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.12.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-legacy</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency> 

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.12.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgis</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgis-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>ST4</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jdom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
          <artifactId>woodstox-core-asl</artifactId>
          <version>4.4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>cis.adapter</groupId>
            <artifactId>CISConnector</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>cis.adapter</groupId>
            <artifactId>CISCore</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google</groupId>
            <artifactId>caplibrary</artifactId>
            <version>r11</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>org.jboss.repository.releases</id>
            <name>JBoss Maven Release Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>OSGEO GeoTools repo</id>
            <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>Hibernate Spatial repo</id>
            <url>http://www.hibernatespatial.org/repository</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.6.RELEASE</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: With eclipse you can inspect the dependency hierarchy, you should compare it before and after removing the module. Alternatively you can use `mvn dependency:tree` and check for your dependency in that.

Comment: I checked the trees after removing the backend-module from the build path and they didn't differ. They shouldn't be depend on the java build path, should they?

Comment: Ohh, I see now, you are manually adding the module in eclipse. This is the problem of course, you should reference it from your `pom.xml` since you already have a maven project. Convert the backend-module to a maven project and install it in your local repository, so you can build the backend outside of your IDE.

Comment: Thanks for the idea but the issue is that it should already be included. The backend-module is a maven project and it is installed as and artifact. Interestingly enough it is not a part of what we've written is missing. It is some part of the spring boot stuff.

Comment: Show us your pom.xml

Comment: I added the pom.xml. Thanks for still taking a look :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the issue was fixed by dropping a lot of the version statements in the pom.xml files and upgrading Spring Boot to the latest version.

If I understood the hastily given explanation correctly our Spring boot release didn't have the right versions of some Spring components packed into it.

Sorry if someone has a similar issue and finds this answer insufficient.